# Get Inserted id in register.php in WHMCS

Tags: php, whmcs

I want to add custom registeration field in `tblclient`. In whmcs here all code works dynamically and logic related files are encrypted so after registration I want to get last inserted id in  hook so that I can update the field with my custom record. Can anyone know the how it can be done.

Sorry all codes are encrypted by default by whmcs so I cant paste it.
For my efforts I know I have to create a hook in hooks folder.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: add some codes ..then only somebody can helps you

Comment: @DreamHunter I cant as all logic related codes are encoded. :( I only know that we can use hook, once client registers it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the ClientAreaRegister hook, it provides you with the ID of the newly created client.  https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/client-area-interface/#clientarearegister

If you need info on how to actually use that you'll have to look through the WHMCS docs on hooks https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks/